# Unable to get send Action from Google ok app to my android app?

Tags: android, manifest, intentfilter, voice-recognition

I am working on a voice recognition feature in my Android app and I am trying to get a send action from a google search or "*ok google*", but my app does not get the send action.

When I say "*ok google send a message*" then google shows only SMS, Whatsapp etc but doesn't show my app.

I have declared an `Intent Filter` in my app `Manifest` file but it doesn't appear in the selection. Any ideas what is missing?

Comment: Have you declare the needed intent filters in your Manifest? A sample for setting activity as share option ; <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.